# laravel 5.2 changing default login function

Tags: php, authentication, authorization, laravel-5

How can I change the default login page on laravel 5.2, I already changed:

```
Added "protected $username = 'my_new_field';" to AuthController.php 
Added "protected $table = 'user';" to Users.php
```

What I wanted to do here is that instead of using email to login, I want to use user_id as username, but even after all those changes I still get:

**"These credentials do not match our records."**, What could be causing this?

Also instead of using "users" table I am using "user"

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of changing laravel default login but only using username instead of email then i would recommend to change on on AuthenticatesUsers.php where u can find the `public function postLogin(Request $request)` and you can change the request need if many fields are to be needed i would recommend you to https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#adding-custom-guards

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by overriding the `getCredentials()` method, in `AuthController`.